# Google analitycs API. Get data by xmla

Tags: google-analytics-api, xmla

Whether there is a possibility of obtaining data and metadata via xmla?
I want to connect to xmla server via olap4j and visualize data from google.

Answer (score 0):

[Google analytics v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#data_response) returns Json not xml. No way to change that.

> If successful, this request returns a response body with the JSON
>   structure defined below. If the output parameter is set to dataTable
>   then the request returns a response body with the JSON (Data Table)
>   structure defined below.